# Error using std::map::at

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, vector, push-back

I have a map defined as:

```
map<std::string,std::vector<message *> > data;
```

Where `std::string` refers to a username (Primary key) and `std::vector<message *>` to the messages corresponding to a particular username. Message is a struct containing message id, time and the message text. Therefore, in order to push back another message, I use the following code:

```
std::vector<message *> messages = data.at[recvbuf_usrn];
messages.push_back(new message(*recvbuf_msg,currentDateTime()));
data[*recvbuf_usrn] = messages;
```

but I get an error:

```
error C3867: 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>::at': function call missing argument list; use '&std::map<_Kty,_Ty>::at' to create a pointer to member
```

Where recvbuf_usrn and recvbuf_msg are defined as follows:

```
std::string *recvbuf_usrn=new std::string;
std::string *recvbuf_msg=new std::string;
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
data.at(recvbuf_usrn);
```

(`at`with parents).
or

```
data[recvbuf_usrn];
```

BTW, that return a reference, so you may simply do:

```
auto& messages = data[recvbuf_usrn];
messages.push_back(new message(*recvbuf_msg, currentDateTime()));
```

You probably also should use smart pointer:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<message>>> data;
```

Answer (score 1):

[`std::map::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) is function, you should call it as:

```
std::vector<message *> messages = data.at(*recvbuf_usrn);
```

If you want to use [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) you should:

```
std::vector<message *> messages = data[*recvbuf_usrn];
```